# Interop.excel pending on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel-interop, windows-server-2012-r2, file-conversion

Using the library interop.excel, when I run the "ExportAsFixedFormat" method, to convert from .xlsx to .pdf, locally it's okay. On the server (Windows Server 2012 r2) this request is in pending without giving errors. The other methods of the library are also fine on the server.

Thanks

Gianluca

Answer (score 2):

As said here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office, it is not supported to automate Office application from server-side code. It is mainly because that a number of complications will occur. The KB article introduces more detailed information. It also suggests that before you involve Office as a server-side component in your project, consider alternatives. Microsoft strongly recommends a number of alternatives that do not require Office to be installed server-side, and that can perform most common tasks more efficiently and more quickly than Automation.

Please refer to the part "Alternatives to server-side Automation" of the KB article.